# Proving equality with floor by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that if $x\notin Z$ then $\lfloor ax \rfloor \neq a \lfloor x \rfloor$ for some $a \in Z$.

I know it can be proven by taking two cases into account: $ax$ being or no being an integer. However, I also thought about a proof by contradiction:

Suppose that if $x\notin Z$ then $\lfloor ax \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor \ \ \ \ \forall a \in Z$. Then, we let $k = \lfloor x \rfloor$ so we have:
$$ k \leq x < k+1 \\ ak \leq ax < ak+a$$

Hence, $ax<a \lfloor x \rfloor +a$ but since $\lfloor ax \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor$ then it means that $ax< \lfloor ax \rfloor +a$ which doesn't hold for $a=0$ so we proved the initial assumption by contradiction.

Is that solution OK or can I not prove such thing this way?

Comment: The proof is wrong. $x < y$ does not imply $ax < ay$ when $a = 0$ whatever $x$ and $y$ mean.

Comment: @copper.hat - yes but where in this problem is there a use for this identity?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė - I know it does not and that's why I say the last inequality doesn't hold which is a basis for the proof. I mean, $ax< \lfloor ax \rfloor +a$ clearly doesn't hold for $a=0$.

Comment: @Straightfw. You wrote $k \leq x < k+1$. Then you multiplied each term by $a$ and wrote $ak \leq ax < ak+a$. But you're not allowed to do that, regardless of what $k$ stands for. This is the point where you introduce the contradiction you later find. It has nothing to do with $\lfloor ax \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Oops, missed that completely. Will delete previous comments. Thanks!

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė - I see. But is the multiplication by $a$ completely illegal or just later using the zero case is wrong?

Comment: If $a>0$ then it's fine. If $a \geq 0$ then you have $ax \leq ak+a$. If $a < 0$ you have to flip the $<$ signs. If you don't know what the sign of $a$ is then you can't compare $ax$ and $ak$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė - right, a naive mistake on my side. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x$ is not an integer, and must show that $a$ exists.

Since $x$ is not an integer, there is a rational number $m/n\in (\lfloor x\rfloor,x)$ with $m$ and $n$ irreducible. What happens when you consider $nx$ and $n\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Answer (score 1):

The OP is actually asking if his/her proof is correct, which it isn't, as Karolis Juodelė has taken pains to explain in comments.  A couple of correct proofs have been given as answers.  Here's another cute, short proof:

> Let $a=-1$.

More precisely, if $x$ is not an integer, then $k\lt x\lt k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, with $\lfloor x\rfloor = k$.  But then $-(k+1)\lt-x\lt-k$, so that $\lfloor -x\rfloor=-(k+1)\not=-k=-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Note, this proof only works because the statement is for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, not $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $nx-1 \le \lfloor nx \rfloor \le nx$ for all $n>0$. Dividing across by $n$ gives
$x-{1 \over n} \le { \lfloor nx \rfloor \over n} \le x$, hence
$\lim_n { \lfloor nx \rfloor \over n} = x$. More or less the same analysis shows that this is true for $n<0$ as well.

Now suppose $\lfloor nx \rfloor = n \lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $n$, then we have
$\lim_n { \lfloor nx \rfloor \over n} = \lfloor x \rfloor = x$, a contradiction,
hence we must have some $n$ such that $\lfloor nx \rfloor \neq n \lfloor x \rfloor$.

In fact, this analysis shows that we can only have $\lfloor nx \rfloor = n \lfloor x \rfloor$ for finitely many $n$.